# JDBC doesn't see the change that ALTER TYPE query in Oracle makes

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using an `object` created by the `CREATE TYPE SOME_OBJECT AS OBJECT` statement. 
For a new requirement, the length of one of the attributes needs to be updated to 11 from 9.

I executed this alter query: 
`ALTER TYPE SOME_OBJECT MODIFY ATTRIBUTE SOME_ATTRIBUTE VARCHAR2(11) CASCADE;`

Now, when I'm using JDBC code for updated values i.e., input with length 11, it gives `Length too long` error.

I looked up Oracle docs. In of the examples of such an alter query, the docs says to `disconnect` and `connect` again.

Initially, I didn't pay attention to the `disconnect` statement. After a lot of trials when I couldn't figure out why it is still giving `Length too long` error. I reset the JDBC pool connection, and it worked.

I don't understand why is this a special case? Is this JDBC connection-pool specific? We have `ALTER TABLE` and host of other queries that doesn't require connection reset for the JDBC code to see the change. Why this very `ALTER` requires connection reset? Am I missing something here?

Comment: The driver caches the information longer than it should?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm not sure. But I don't see this behavior with other `ALTER` queries, or other DDLs for that matter.

Comment: Just guessing, but likely the driver loads the types once per database to build the type map, and reuses their definition. This avoids the overhead of having to query it each time you use them.